# excel chart: how to change data points format in part of the curve?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Suppose I have a curve of x(t), data points are shown as blue squres.

Is it possible to easily set it, so that when x(t) is less than 0, the point will be shown as red circle?

I know each data point could be manually modified, but hope there's a way to automatically do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One work-around would be to split your data into 2 series.

In the screen shot below, note the formulas used in columns C and D.  Those are the 2 series plotted in the graph. The NA() function returns #N/A, which fortunately does NOT get plotted.

I chose line graphs with markers-and-lines, but then suppressed the line part and changed the markers as desired.

[image]

Comment: thanks! mmm... so there is nothing similar to the "conditional formatting"?